# Does the standard require that objects in automatic storage have the correct alignment for any type (e.g. as malloc does)?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm curious if allocating a buffer on the stack is required to have correct alignment for any type, similar to how `malloc` works, or if I would be forced to use something like `std::aligned_storage`.

Consider the following block of code:

```
typedef enum _KEY_VALUE_INFORMATION_CLASS {
    KeyValueBasicInformation            = 0,
    // Others
} KEY_VALUE_INFORMATION_CLASS;

typedef struct _KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION {
    ULONG TitleIndex;
    ULONG Type;
    ULONG NameLength;
    WCHAR Name[1];
} KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PKEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION;

std::vector<std::wstring> RegistryKey::EnumerateValueNames() const
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> result;
    ULONG index = 0;
    const ULONG valueNameStructSize = 16384 * sizeof(wchar_t) +
        sizeof(KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION);

    // Stack buffer here
    unsigned char buff[valueNameStructSize];
    // Casted here
    KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION const* basicValueInformation =
        reinterpret_cast<KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION const*>(buff);
    for(;;)
    {
        ULONG resultLength;
        NTSTATUS errorCheck = PNtEnumerateValueKeyFunc(
            hKey_,
            index++,
            KeyValueBasicInformation,
            buff,
            valueNameStructSize,
            &resultLength);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(errorCheck))
        {
            result.emplace_back(std::wstring(basicValueInformation->Name,
                basicValueInformation->NameLength / sizeof(wchar_t)));
        }
        else if (errorCheck == STATUS_NO_MORE_ENTRIES)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Win32Exception::ThrowFromNtError(errorCheck);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note how the value `buff` is a character buffer put on the stack, sized to hold a given maximum amount of data. However, I'm concerned that the cast required to interpret the buffer as a string may cause an alignment fault if this code were to be ported to another (say ARM or IA64) platform.

EDIT: If anyone's curious, I redid this in terms of `std::aligned_storage` and `std::alignment_of`:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> RegistryKey::EnumerateValueNames() const
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> result;
    ULONG index = 0;
    const ULONG valueNameStructSize = 16384 * sizeof(wchar_t) +
        sizeof(KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION);
    std::aligned_storage<valueNameStructSize,
        std::alignment_of<KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION>::value>::type buff;
    auto basicValueInformation =
        reinterpret_cast<KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION*>(&buff);
    for(;;)
    {
        ULONG resultLength;
        NTSTATUS errorCheck = PNtEnumerateValueKeyFunc(
            hKey_,
            index++,
            KeyValueBasicInformation,
            basicValueInformation,
            valueNameStructSize,
            &resultLength);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(errorCheck))
        {
            result.emplace_back(std::wstring(basicValueInformation->Name,
                basicValueInformation->NameLength / sizeof(wchar_t)));
        }
        else if (errorCheck == STATUS_NO_MORE_ENTRIES)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Win32Exception::ThrowFromNtError(errorCheck);
        }
    }
    return std::move(result);
}
```

Comment: You will indeed need to take care of alignment yourself. C++11 has an `alignas` keyword to help with that. (Note that by contrast `new char[]` memory is guaranteed to be aligned for the maximum alignment.)

Comment: I can't find anything, nor think of any reason for it.  You'll have to use `alignas`

Comment: @MooingDuck: The "reason" would be to allow code like the above. Though I agree it's kind of an edge case. And here I thought `aligned_storage` was only for people implementing things like `vector`!

Comment: @ildjarn: I'd assume the allocator is required to `allocate` memory that is aligned for the template type of the allocator, also avoiding the problem.  You're right that my reasoning was 100% wrong though.

Comment: This is something I never paid much attention to, but I have seen in the past the alignment forced in the code. Reserve 7 extra chars and then obtain a pointer to the location you need with pointer arithmetic. Not nice, but it ensures that you get the proper alignment.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I've just replaced my char buffer with `std::aligned_storage` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard makes no requirements on the alignment of automatic variables (or variables with static storage for that matter), other than the compiler must make sure that accessing them works.

- C++03 3.9/5 Types

> Object types have alignment requirements (3.9.1, 3.9.2).  The
>   alignment of a complete object type is an implementation-defined
>   integer value representing a number of bytes; an object is allocated
>   at an address that meets the alignment requirements of its object type

Note: "object type" here means a type that's not a function, reference or void type, (i.e., it applies to `unsigned char`).

One way to get an aligned buffer might be to declare `buff` like so:

```
KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION buff[valueNameStructSize/sizeof(KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION) + 1];
```

And you'll be able to get rid of the `reinterpret_cast<>` to boot.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, that will construct/destruct automatically won't it?

Comment: @MooingDuck: But what's being constructed is an array of a POD struct.  It'll be at least as large as the array of `unsigned char` in the original and will be guaranteed to have the right alignment for a `KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION` struct.  This technique shouldn't be used for a non-POD. Maybe it shouldn't be used at all, but it'll work with any implementation where the 'struct hack' idiom (http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html) works.

Comment: IMO this solution is not viable in general, as there are many Windows APIs (e.g. [`SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551973(v=vs.85).aspx)) that return dynamically-sized data, and you have no choice but to use an (`unsigned`) `char` buffer + cast.

Comment: @ildjarn: Who's talking about dynamically sized data? the question was specifically about a buffer allocated as an automatic variable. If you need dynamically sized data, then you have to get the memory dynamically.

Comment: The OP is kludging dynamically sized data by highballing the allocation size (hence the 16384, to make room for `KEY_VALUE_BASIC_INFORMATION::Name`). I would expect a real solution to require no kludges.

Comment: @ildjarn: Not really a kludge; simply trying to avoid a dynamic allocation when the maximum size is known and reasonable for the stack. (Windows limits the number of characters in a name to that value) No reason to pay for the dynamic allocation where it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Billy : Understood, but many APIs to not have a known upper bound, and if there were a good solution to those APIs, it would certainly be a better solution for you as well. :-] That being said, I think you nailed it with `std::aligned_storage` + `std::alignment_of`.

Comment: @ildjarn: If there's no defined upper bound, then I just use `std::vector<unsigned char>`, which is required to do the "right thing" because it's based on a plain dynamically allocated memory buffer, which is mandated to satisfy any type's alignment requirements.

Comment: @ildjarn: Example: https://bitbucket.org/BillyONeal/instalog/src/b141398a2b6d/LogCommon/Registry.cpp#cl-271

Comment: @Billy : And http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/6a7cb7c7-b426-4634-ba39-8e0592cf1f56 ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: I don't see any alignment problems there.

Comment: Strictly speaking an `allocator` for a container (including the default one) is only required to return an address with an alignment appropriate for `T`, the type the container is parametrized on: C++11 20.6.9.1/5 "Returns: A pointer to the initial element of an array of storage of size n * sizeof(T), aligned appropriately for objects of type T"  So the storage for a `vector<unsigned char>` has a very, very weak alignment requirement.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Hmm.. interesting point. Do you know of any default allocator implementation that does not just forward to `new`?

Comment: @Billy: no.  I haven't looked at details of default allocator implementations, but I'd bet that all mainstream default allocators just pass through to the global `operator new()`. I imagine that in practice there's no danger (particularly on Windows), but I think it's a problem from a language lawyer's view..

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Ok, I don't think I'm going to mess with it then. Worst case if it does become an alignment fault issue or perf problem I can always supply an allocator that *does* simply forward to operator new.